# Commits not linking to Github account

Tags: git, github

I made a repository online on github and then cloned it to my linux desktop. I pushed a few commits but noticed they were greyed out on the commits page. [image: Commits are greyed out]

These commits don't show up on my profile page. When I check the .patch for these commits I see my username but a different email. Both emails are linked to my account. Is there a way to link these commits to my account?

Answer (score 1):

Open Git Bash. Create a fresh, bare clone of your repository:

```
git clone --bare https://github.com/user/repo.git    
cd repo.git
```

Then, copy and paste the script, replacing the following variables based
    on the information you gathered:

```
#!/bin/sh

git filter-branch --env-filter '
OLD_EMAIL="your-old-email@example.com"
CORRECT_NAME="Your Correct Name"
CORRECT_EMAIL="your-correct-email@example.com"
if [ "$GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL" = "$OLD_EMAIL" ]
then
    export GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="$CORRECT_NAME"
    export GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="$CORRECT_EMAIL"
fi
if [ "$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL" = "$OLD_EMAIL" ]
then
    export GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="$CORRECT_NAME"
    export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="$CORRECT_EMAIL"
fi
' --tag-name-filter cat -- --branches --tags
```

Press Enter to run the script. Review the new Git history for errors. Push the corrected history to GitHub:

```
git push --force --tags origin 'refs/heads/*'
```

Clean up the temporary clone:

```
cd ..
rm -rf repo.git
```

That's it.

Comment: This looks like it changes my old commits to using the original email. Is there any way for commits that use either email to show up correctly?